# Crystal Report Webform_initcallback is not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

Crystal report does not load at runtime.

Please see the attached image.

I am done routing in `global.asmx` my project.

[image]

Comment: My reports were not loading as well. It was only showing that blue title bar like you. My issue was with the url rewriting. It was done incorrectly.